# Ansible: scp file from non-inventory node

Tags: ansible, devops

I need to `scp` a file from a non-inventory Remote Machine to an in-inventory Remote Machine in Ansible. The `scp` also requires a password to access. Is there a straightforward ansible way to do this?

E.g.:
My inventory

```yaml
hosts:
  - node1
  - node2
```

Machine where file is present:

```yaml
  - gw_machine
```

On `node1`, I want to:

```bash
scp user@gw_machine:/path/ .
```

I am aware of `copy`, `fetch` and `synchronize` modules but they don't seem to do the job for me. I tried writing an `expect` script but it gets hung when I connect for the first time as the `gw_machine` is not in `known_hosts` of `node1`.

My expect task:

```yaml
  - name: Scp file
    shell: |
      set timeout -1
      spawn /usr/bin/scp user@gw_machine:/path_to_file/ .
      expect "password:"
      send "{{gw_passwd}}\n"
      expect EOF
      exit 0
    args:
      chdir: /tmp/
      executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

The above works when `gw_machine` is in known hosts of `node1`, but hangs when it's not. I don't have `sshpass` on the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `shell` task with the `sshpass`. `sshpass` will pass the password `scp` needs, example below:

```bash
sshpass -p "<the password here>" scp <username>@<host IP>:<path and file> .
```

**EDIT:**

In case you want to stick with your existing task, you can tune the `scp` command to automatically add the new host to its `known_hosts` list, by adding the `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no`:

For example:

```bash
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tmp]$ scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no /tmp/test1.out localhost:/tmp/test2.out
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
test1.out
100% 0 0.0KB/s 00:00
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tmp]$
```

Comment: I should have probably added a comment I don't have sshpass on the remote.

Comment: That will not work as we have a password requirement for the scp

Comment: i am suggesting to update your "expect task" that your provided, because "The above works when gw_machine is in known hosts of node1, but hangs when it's not." since you are saying the problem is when you are scp-ing to new host, try to add the `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the scp command.

Comment: Got you. Another solution I used was to turn off HostkeyChecking in ssh config but this is better. For anyone else who reads this, note that this is not the most secure solution. Turning off host key checking opens you to MITM attacks.